# How to do undo in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data factory. While developing the pipeline I could not find undo operation in Azure Data Factory. `ctrl+z` did not work. What is the keyboard shortcut for the undo?

Answer (score 7):

There is no undo shortcut for ADF. Max you can do is the Discard All option.

[image: Discard All Option]

Answer (score 1):

If you are in git mode, you're able to revert any change using a git method of choice. ADF basically stores a few .json files in your git repo, any saves you make in the UI is pushed to the git repository. Changes made in your development branch will also be reflected in the UI after a page refresh.

For example, installing Github for Windows & cloning your collaboration branch enables you to see any change that has been done and which JSON was affected.

- Right clicking on a commit, and clicking 'revert commit' reverses the selected change. Push it back to your remote git repository, and refresh your page on ADF to see the changes reflected.
- If you want to selectively undo, you're going to have to change the JSON yourself in order to partially undo a commit

  - save all your current changes, even though there are ones you do not want.
  - use the line-by-line differences provided by git (in your most recent changes) in order to identify / isolate your changes, adjust them & push these changes back to the collaboration branch.\